# Services in Redmine-Plugin

Tags: redmine

i've made a plugin for redmine, with 2 services.

But, on my remote-machine, the services seems not to be loaded.

- Do services in redmine-plugins work in general?
- Do i have to set any autoload-paths?
- Is there a version-difference, in Redmine?

On my local Macbook, within redmine-4.0.4 all works fine (env: production and development). But on my Debian, there is redmine-3.4.2 i receipt this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant TimesController::SearchTimes):
  plugins/billing/app/controllers/times_controller.rb:41:in `select'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are just Ruby objects so they surely work in Redmine plugins.

Redmine autoloads only `controllers`, `helpers` and `models` paths under the plugin's `/app` directory. Plugin starting point `/init.rb` should manually `require` other files which usually resides in `/lib` folder.

Redmine 3.x and 4.x versions are very different, but much of these changes are caused by Rails itself.